Counting duplicate values in one column based on the value from another in Excel?
I have a very large dataset which changes information and size on a daily basis (data is pulled from a very old, not very user friendly WMS).
I need to add a column to count how many unique item numbers are on each order number in a similar format as the snippet below if possible.
Problem is that I am unable to remove duplicates or add filters because each line has unique data that is used elsewhere.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried a few different formulas but my knowledge is not the best and searching the web has not helped in this instance...



Order no.
Item no.
Item Count




568320
20436
1


568320
20436



568733
62509
1


568733
62509



568669
62418
2


568669
61016



568738
62249
2


568738
62546



568724
61024
3


568724
59955



568724
20436



568720
62418
3


568720
56599



568720
61033



568999
62726
2


568999
56609



568891
62486
2


568891
62454





Maybe use UNIQUE to get a list of all items you need to count and then COUNTIF to count them?

Thanks for the reply. Problem with that is there will be duplicate item numbers for different order numbers. I need to know how many unique item numbers are on each order...

Unless I badly misunderstand, UNIQUE would do this. Maybe edit your question to include a sample output

Do you sometimes repeat an item number for a given order number?

Here is one alternative method to accomplish the desired output, and since you are using Structured References hence formulas using the references as well:


=IF(SUM(--(INDEX([Order no.],1):[@[Order no.]]=[@[Order no.]]))=1,
SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER([Item no.],[Order no.]=[@[Order no.]]))<>"")),"")


Or, Using Dynamic Array Formula to spill if preferred then:
=LET(
     a, OrderTbl,
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     MAP(b, LAMBDA(r, IF(SUM(N(r:OrderTbl[@[Order no.]]=r))=1,
     SUM(1-ISERR(UNIQUE(FILTER(TAKE(a,,-1),b=r)))),""))))



This is perfect! Thank you!


a very large dataset which changes information and size on a daily basis

I'm assuming it is not in table format, I have used ranges, please adjust the values to match your dataset.
I have used a helper column based on frequency to show the counts.
=LET(
    comment_1, "Instead the whole col (f.ex. G:G), set to a suitable max",
    last_data_cell, $B$8000,
    data, $A$2:INDEX($B$2:last_data_cell, COUNTA($A$2:$A$8000)),
    order_no, INDEX(data, , 1),
    item_no, INDEX(data, , 2),
    order_no_freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(order_no, order_no), -1),
    row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    MAP(
        row_indices,
        LAMBDA(i,
            IF(
                INDEX(order_no_freq, i),
                ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(item_no, order_no = INDEX(order_no, i)))),
                ""
            )
        )
    )
)


